# How can I dismiss the android keyguard using adb intent

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, keyguard

I am looking for a way to use ADB to dismiss the keyguard in order to automate some tasks.

I would like to start an ACTIVITY (perhaps to call the public method disableKeyguard in android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock), because I assume that it will work on all (or most) Android devices, but I am unsure of the syntax.

I do not wish to use MonkeyRunner, because it is not present (or perhaps, callable) on all devices.  I also cannot send a MENU keycode (adb shell input keycode 82), because this does not dismiss the keyguard on all devices.

Currently I am sending events (low-level touch events), but this needs to be customized for each device, so it is a time consuming task.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Why is MonkeyRunner not callable on all devices? Can you give an example of a device where MonkeyRunner is not callable or could you post the code that you are using to call it?

Answer (score 1):

The "Activity Testing" article has a section called [Unlocking the emulator or device](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html#UnlockDevice) that addresses this situation.

In short, there isn't a way to do it directly with `adb` but using `disableKeyguard()` isn't complicated (see the three lines of example code in the article linked to above).  You could easily put together a little app that does nothing but disable the keyguard.  It would then just be a matter of

```bsh
adb install <apk>
adb shell am start <package>/.<activity>
# Whatever you need to automate
adb uninstall <package>
```

(Where `<apk>`, `<package>`, and `<activity>` all refer to the tiny app that just disables the keyguard.)

Comment: Thanks Darshan.  Unfortunately, deploying an app is not a good option in this case.